# Force Displayport Speed

Tags: displayport

I'm usign a Linux PC to sent a video to a displayport sink OUT OF STANDARD that is not supporting the Displayport link speed at 1.62 Gbit.

When using Linux as a source the policy to negotiate the link speed and the lanes count is to choose the slowest speed and the fewer lanes, provided that this is enough to carry the selected resolution (which is very reasonable). Windows instead just goes for the maximum supported.

Now I'm in the very unlucky condition where my system works with a windows based source but not with a Linux one.

Is there a way to force the displayport Link speed with Linux? Maybe even by patching the kernel? The actual hardware is using the i915 drivers, I'm assuming that this feature is video-card specific.

Thanks!

edit:

looks like editing

drivers/gpu/drm/i915/display/intel_dp.c

did the trick,

```
intel_dp_set_source_rates(struct intel_dp *intel_dp)
{
    /* The values must be in increasing order */
    static const int icl_rates[] = {
        162000, 216000, 270000, 324000, 432000, 540000, 648000, 810000,
        1000000, 1350000,
    };
    static const int bxt_rates[] = {
        162000, 216000, 243000, 270000, 324000, 432000, 540000
    };
    static const int skl_rates[] = {
        162000, 216000, 270000, 324000, 432000, 540000
    };
    static const int hsw_rates[] = {
        162000, 270000, 540000
    };
    static const int g4x_rates[] = {
        162000, 270000
    };
```

Removing the unwanted speed from the array will cause the source to exclude it from the speed negotiation.
Of course in my case removing 162000 will make my DP source out of standard since this value is the fallback one and cannot be unsupported.